# Google satellite XYZ tile layer does not display with QGIS 3.16.1

Tags: satellite, google, display, xyz-tiles

Since I install QGIS ver 3.16.1 the Google satellite XYZ tile does not display.
The URL I use is the `http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`
I have no problem with OSM `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`
or Google Hybrid, `http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`

Comment: Did it work before? When? Where did you get the URL from? What does QGIS' network log say?

Comment: Is this free to use or do we have to pay for it to be legal?

Answer (score 1):

Try [http://mt.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D) - that works for me. (Replaced www with mt)